# Protect JBoss 7 Against Beast attack using SSL configuration

Tags: apache, jboss, jboss7.x

The use of SSLv3.0/TLSv1.0 in combination with certain encryption techniques (CBC block
ciphers) may allow for an attacker to predict the so-called Initialization Vector of subsequent SSL packets. Using this information the attacker can access the secure session of another user. This attack, named BEAST (Browser Exploit Against SSL/TLS), is aimed at the user’s browser and not at the web server. Nevertheless, it is possible to take countermeasures at the server side as well to prevent a successful attack.

The complete solution to this problem is disabling or deprioritizing the support for
vulnerable encryption ciphers (CBC block ciphers) when using SSLv3.0/TLSv1.0. Commonly, this can be achieved by prioritizing RC4 ciphers in the cipher negotiation process.

For Apache web servers that support SSLv3.0/TLSv1.0 this can be configured by adding the
following configuration:

```
SSLProtocol All –SSlv2
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:HIGH:!ADH
```

For Apache web servers that support SSLv3.1/TLSv1.1 and higher, it is recommended to use the following configuration:

```
SSLProtocol All –SSlv2
SSLHonorCipherOrder On  
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!AESGCM
```

As far as I know, JBoss 7 is based on a version of Apache that supports SSLv3.1/TLSv1.1 (maybe I am wrong), so the second alternative can be applied to JBoss 7.

My question is: **Where/How should I configure it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont paranoid with beast attack. According to [this](http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/article/404669/oracle_patches_java_flaw_exploited_ssl_beast_attack/) Oracle fix the issue, its not related directly with JBoss its an JVM issue. As stated [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8174/why-was-the-beast-attack-previously-considered-implausible) its hard to apply beast attack in real world. Just make sure that your JVM and JBoss is up-to-date. If you have still question in your mind its best practice to run JBoss behind a reverse proxy such as apache or nginx.

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct because I completely agree with it. But I will need some help about how to tell to my client "dont paranoid with beast attack" =P